# How do I generate a dictionary using elements of a list as keys and their corresponding digits from a matrix as values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, matrix

So I have a list

> List = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']

and a matrix file in .txt

> - a 12 15 16 13
> - b 9  83 24 72
> - c 4  52 17 93
> - d 12 84 33 80
> - e 29 25 33 47
> - f 82 11 18 9
> - g 12 21 93 77

How should I write the code such that my dictionary keys are elements of the list and the values are the number in the matrix file?
e.g.

> dictionary = {'a':[12,15,16,13],'b':[9,83,24,72].....}

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include your code.

Comment: Where do you need that list for if you have keys in your file?

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like that

```
d = {}                                                                                                                                                                                              

with open('t.txt') as f: 
       for i in f: 
          l = i.split() 
          d[l[0]] = l[1::] 


In [7]: d                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[7]: 
{'a': ['12', '15', '16', '13'],
 'b': ['9', '83', '24', '72'],
 'c': ['4', '52', '17', '93'],
 'd': ['12', '84', '33', '80'],
 'e': ['29', '25', '33', '47'],
 'f': ['82', '11', '18', '9'],
 'g': ['12', '21', '93', '77']}
```

updating with int value
change line to `d[l[0]] = list(map(int, l[1::]))`

```
with open('t.txt') as f: 
    for i in f: 
        l = i.split() 
        print(l) 
        d[l[0]] = list(map(int, l[1::]))
```

output

```
Out[18]: 
{'a': [12, 15, 16, 13],
 'b': [9, 83, 24, 72],
 'c': [4, 52, 17, 93],
 'd': [12, 84, 33, 80],
 'e': [29, 25, 33, 47],
 'f': [82, 11, 18, 9],
 'g': [12, 21, 93, 77]}
```

Comment: This creates list of strings when list of intetgers was needed.

Comment: d[l[0]] = [int(i) for i in l[1::]]

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {}
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        w = line.split() # w is a list of strings in the current line
        dict[l[0]] = [int(w[i]) for i in range(1, len(w))]
print(dict)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.